# r loop multiple data frames with variable rows

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, double, rename

I fear there's a simple solution to this: 
I have a set of data frames, all of them containing the same columns. The only difference is that the amount of rows differs in each data frame.

Say df1 has 10 rows and 5 variables, df2 has 23 rows and 5 variables, df3 has 7 rows.

What I want to do is to assign another data frame dfX to each row of each df, naming the new data frames according to df number and row number.

```
dflist <- list(df1,df2,df3)

for(i in 1:length(dflist)){ 
  for(j in 1:nrow(dflist[[i]]))
    nam <- paste("bat",i,j,sep=".")
    df <- dfX
    assign(nam,df)   
}
```

It seems to work, but it is only giving me three data frames namend df.1.10, df.2.23 and df.3.7.

I expected it to return df.1.1, df.1.2 and so on

Comment: `library(fortunes); fortune(236)`

Comment: Based on your example, you want to have the same dfX repeated 40(10+23+7) times named with different names? Why?

Comment: dfX contains large energy data. I'm going to implement this energy data to each of the newly created data frames so I can apply  calculations and identify each of the potential for each df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing {} for the second for loop. Also dfX is not defined in the example. See updated code below. I added some comments for clarity.

```
# Sample data
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(42,10,5))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(42,23,5))
df3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(42,7,5))
dflist <- list(df1,df2,df3)

# Loop through data frames
for(i in 1:length(dflist)){ 

  # Loop through rows
  for(j in 1:nrow(dflist[[i]])) {
    nam <- paste("bat",i,j,sep=".") # Create name
    df <- dflist[[i]][1:j,] # Subset data frame
    assign(nam,df) # Assign name
  }
}

# List workspace content
ls()
```

Hopefully this gets you closer to what you need!